# Как использовать союз "Не то что(бы)..., а(но)"?

Tags: союзы

В интернете встретил следующие предложения:

> 1. Я *не то чтобы* поесть, *а* поспать не смогу;
> 2. Мама *не то чтобы* сердилась, *но* все-таки была недовольна.

В обоих предложениях используется двойной союз *"не то что(бы)..., а(но)"*.
Предполагаю, что части этого союза "а" и "но" эквивалентны в своем значении как часть этого союза.

Читаю определение этого союза:

> Не То Чтобы.., А и Не То Чтоб.., А Не То Чтобы.., А и Не То Чтоб.., А
> разг. союз 1. Употр. при присоединении части предложения, в которой
> выражается неопределенное отрицание того, что более точно
> формулируется во второй части предложения; не то чтобы.., но
>
> Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.

Не понимаю, где "неопределенное отрицание" и то, что "более точно формулируется" во второй части предложения в предложении 1.
Предполагаю, что автор предложения 1 имел в виду: "Я не смогу поесть, не говоря уже о том, чтобы поспать."

Автор предложения 1 неправильно использовал двойной союз?

Answer (score 2):

**СОЮЗЫ НЕ ОДИНАКОВЫ:**
Между союзами ‟не то что Х, а Y” и ‟не то чтобы X, а Y” есть разница:
В союзе ‟не то что Х, а Y” Х от Y отличается значительно — X намного больше или намного меньше Y, или что-то подобное; а в союзе ‟не то чтобы X, а Y” Х незначительно отличается от Y — это корректировка ответа в немного большую или немного меньшую сторону. Взгляните на примеры:

> Не то что помочь, а спасти меня, – сказал Евгений. (Помочь и спасти значительно отличаются. Нельзя употребить ‟чтобы”.)

> Не то чтобы понравился ей, а... как бы выразится... заинтересовал, что ли. (Понравился и заинтересовал близки. Нельзя употребить ‟что”.)

> Я так примечаю, что скоро не то что дичи, а никакой птицы не останется. (Отсутствие дичи и отсутствие дичи и птицы сильно отличается. Нельзя употребить ‟чтобы”.)

> В ту минуту я не то чтобы струсил, а немного оробел. (Струсил и оробел не сильно отличаются. Нельзя употребить ‟что”.)

**ПРАВИЛЬНОСТЬ УПОТРЕБЛЕНИЯ ПЕРВОГО ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ:**
Союз употреблен правильно, так как если было бы так: ‟Я не то что поесть, а поспать не смогу”, то это было бы семантической ошибкой, так как если человек не может поесть, то это более серьезная проблема, чем бессонница. Смысл предложения примерно следующий (если перефразировать): ‟Состояние мое тяжелое — я не могу спать, но не настолько тяжелое, чтобы я не мог есть”.
**ПО ПОВОДУ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ:**
Я не понимаю, что в этом отрицании неопределенного, как и не понимаю, какая такая большая точность во второй части. Это просто плохое определение.
**РАЗНИЦА МЕЖДУ ‟НО” И ‟А” В ТАКИХ СОЮЗАХ:**
На первый взгляд, где-то заменяемы, а где-то нет. Это общий вопрос разницы между союзами ‟но” и ‟а”, а не просто ‟но” и ‟а” внутри этого союза. Я уже не буду это расписывать, так как это потребует много времени (потребуется рассмотреть много предложений), уж извините.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131717/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett-------).

Answer (score 2):

1. Союзы НЕ ТО ЧТОБЫ...НО, НЕ ТО ЧТО... А  – это  **градационные союзы**. Градация признака – это постепенность в переходе от одного признака к другому, например: близкий – недалекий – не очень близкий – далекий и т.д.
2. Это **двойные** союзы; во второй части используется союз А или НО, причем  их нужно правильно выбрать.

**Союз НО.** Даются две оценки ситуации, из которых вторая болеет точная и правильная, а первая неверная или недостаточно точная.
Например: До Ниццы от Йера не то чтобы далеко, но и не рукой подать (не очень близко). Один наблюдатель считает, что далеко, другой  же **отрицает** это мнение и дает более точную градационную характеристику. Союз НО – противительный, поэтому он подходит к данному случаю.

**Союз А** – **сопоставительный**, он не отрицает, а предлагает **другое описание,** например: До Ниццы от Йера не то чтобы
далеко, а просто неудобно добираться на транспорте. Отрицания здесь
нет, но есть **сопоставление двух оценок в какой-то теме**.

3. Другой пример **с разными союзами**: Мама не то чтобы очень рассердилась, но была нами недовольна. Мама не то чтобы расстроилась,
   а была не такой веселой, как всегда.

**4. Текстовые примеры**

(1) Не сказать, чтобы это выступление сломило лед, но конфронтацию несколько ослабило.

Позавчера поместили в больницу одного товарища, не сказать чтобы сумасшедшего, но был этот товарищ основательно не в себе.

(2) Голова не то что болела, а была какая-то совсем пустая, гремучая.

Она не то что пополнела, а как-то огрубела, обозначилась.

5. Иногда союзы **взаимозаменяемы**, так как союз А может использоваться для выражения несоответствия, как и союз НО:

Я не то чтобы поесть, а (даже) поспать не смогу.

Я не то чтобы поесть, но и поспать не смогу.

Answer (score 1):

Так люди говорят.

Примеры Розенталя:
*Нынче не то что солдат, а мужичков видал* (Толстой).
*В ту минуту я не то чтобы струсил, а немного оробел* (Куприн).

*Я не то чтобы поесть, а поспать не смогу.*
Отрицание, потому что частица НЕ (до запятой).
А более точно формулируется во второй части предложения то, что он не может сделать.

На мой взгляд, использование НО в этом союзе устарело, например:
*За дорогой не то чтоб пустыня – но пейзаж без домов и людей.*

Update:
Хоть с "чтобы" и звучит, но если более строго, то надо так:
*Я не то **что** поесть, а поспать не смогу.*
Почему?
Потому что при "не то что" нет отрицания, например:
*Он принёс не то что [не только] шоколадку, а полную торбу сладостей.* || Шоколадку тоже принёс, она не отрицается.
А при "не то чтобы" обычно есть:
*Он купил не то чтобы [не совсем] шоколадку, а шоколадный батончик.* || Шоколадку не купил, она отрицается. Здесь "что" вместо "чтобы" не звучит и не подходит.
А та разница, о которой говорит Jim Korbett, лишь следствие этого.

В нашем примере очевидно, что он и есть не может (кусок в горло не лезет), и заснуть не сможет. Нет отрицания. Или ещё кто-то, кроме Jim Korbett, видит другой смысл? Его смысл не сильно подходит из-за того, что глаголы слишком разные (не подходит замена на "не совсем", которое указано в словаре).
Скорее всего, о таком отрицании говорится в словаре.

В версии словаря Ефремовой 2006 года так:
*не то чтобы* част.; = *не то чтоб* Употребляется при выражении неопределённости оценки признака или действия.

Comment: Вам, может быть, и очевидно, а может быть вот такая ситуация: Человек попал в аварию, а потом в больницу. Если у него бессонница, то это одно, но если он не может поесть — он овощ! и его кормят через трубку. Он говорит: ‟Я не то чтобы поесть, а поспать не смогу”. Здесь что-то неправильно в таком контексте?

Comment: Так здесь у вас "поесть" не отрицается, и надо "не то что".

Comment: Я не то чтобы поесть, а поспать не смогу. = Ситуация плохая настолько, что у меня бессонница, но не плохая настолько уж, чтобы я не мог поесть. Всё здесь идеально. Навязываете какую-то субъективщину.

Comment: Не говорят так люди в таком случае. Скажут так: *Я не поесть, а поспать не смогу.* **Не то чтобы = не совсем.**

Comment: Может, вы допускаете следующее: *Я не совсем поесть, а поспать не смогу.* Это разговорный (не особо правильный) вариант.

Comment: Ваше предложение: ‟Я не поесть, а поспать не смогу” — имеет существенное различие.  Требуется такое: ‟Не настолько уж все плохо, чтобы я не мог поесть, но всё же я не смогу поспать.” Ваше предложение упускает этот градационный элемент. Я больше не хочу спорить на эту тему. Если вы так считаете, то пожалуйста.

Comment: Мне кажется, что это и так (без расшифровки) понятно, просто так более резко. Понятно, что разница есть. Мысль была в том, что скажут как-то по-другому, а не именно так. Кстати, чем ближе оппонент к истине, тем меньше сил, желания и возможностей спорить.

Comment: Чем ближе оппонент к дурке, тем также меньше сил, желания и возможностей спорить.

Comment: Хм, ну и это тоже. Но мы всё-таки в процессе дискуссии становились ближе к истине (я уж точно, не без вашей помощи).

Answer (score 1):

В моём предыдущем ответе указано, когда какой союз употребляется. Это употребление является классическим.

Обобщим:
*не то чтобы* — не совсем это, а вот это; || В начале преувеличение.
*не то что* — не только это, а даже это. || В начале преуменьшение.

Порой и в первом случае употребляется "не то что" — не классический случай, возможно разговорный.
Но наоборот нет: "не то чтобы" не употребляется во втором случае:
*Я так примечаю, что скоро не то чтобы дичи, а никакой птицы не останется.*
Но перед глаголами оно звучит лучше. Просто "чтобы" более естественно перед глаголами.

Comment: Решил добавить примеры из статьи, где исследуется этот союз (https://e-koncept.ru/2017/970207.htm):
«Андрей Звягинцев на мою рецензию не то чтобы
обиделся, но отозвался о ней глубоко недоброжелательно» [Д. Быков. Мимо.
Новая газета. №4 от 19.01.201]

«Звонят мне с нескольких телеканалов в день, причём с таких телеканалов, где не
то что лично меня показывать нельзя, но даже упоминать книжки не
рекомендовано» [ Д. Быков. Эхо Москвы. «Бильжо мне друг». 21.12.2016]

Comment: Вы что-то нашли для себя в этой статье, кроме примеров?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы так истолковал семантику этих сочинительных сопоставительных союзов:

1. Я не то чтобы поесть, а поспать не смогу.

Во-первых, употребление в этом предложении союза "не то чтобы..., а..." — неудачно. Я бы использовал именно союз "не то что..., а...".

Я не то что поесть, а (даже) поспать не смогу.

Не то что X, а Y

Значение: X ещё можно терпеть, а Y— совсем уж вопиющий случай, с которым смириться трудно.

Я не то что поесть, а поспать не смогу.

То есть ладно бы только отсутствие кормёжки (это ещё можно терпеть), но ведь ещё и отсутствие сна (это совсем худо, товарищи).

Употребление "не то чтобы..., а" в этом предложении, скорее всего, ошибочно. Думается, что автор хотел сказать как раз: "Я не то что поесть, а поспать не смогу", но по какой-то причине вместо "не то что" употребил "не то чтобы".

Не нужно неудачное (или ошибочное) употребление превращать в некое важное явления, заслуживающее пристального внимания, заслуживающее быть объектом исследования и истолкования.

2. Мама не то чтобы сердилась, но все-таки была недовольна.

Не то чтобы X, но всё таки Y

Значение: X вроде как не совсем точно передаёт состояние мамы, а вот Y — максимально точно.

Вот гипотетический пример с другим союзом — союзом "и":

Мама сердилась "и" была недовольна.

Союз "и" соединяет равноправные одномоментные состояния мамы.

Меняем союз "и" на "не то чтобы...  а...":

И этот двойной союз ставит эти однородные сказуемые — сердилась, была недовольна — в иные семантико-синтаксические отношения друг с другом: первое состояние будет не совсем верным с точки зрения говорящего, зато второе — верным максимально:

— Эй, Петя, мама сердилась?

— Мама не то чтобы сердилась (не совсем точная формулировка относительно её состояния), но все-таки была недовольна (более верное описание её состояния).